# Azure Pipeline not using private project nugget packages (artifacts)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, nuget-package

I am trying to run a pipeline that will produce an artifact ([...].Models) for my private project's artifact/package feed.
It relies on another artifact ([...].Interfaces) that I have successfully created and used locally on my machine, but it fails once I run the pipeline with the error

```
error NU1101: Unable to find package [...].Interfaces. 
No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

I have the following configs in my .yaml file.

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: dotnet pack
inputs:
command: 'pack'
packagesToPack: '**/[...].Models.csproj'
versioningScheme: 'byBuildNumber'
feedsToUse: 'select'
vstsFeed: '[...]'
```

What modifications can I make?